# Remove prefix of each line in a file and output to another file using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a source code file in which comments are prefixed with `//` (ie. double slashes and an empty space), I want to convert the source code into a document so I tried to `cat file.c` and pipe it to `sed`, the thinking is to replace "double slash and a space" if a line starts with it, with empty string, but it looks like the slash has some special meaning in `sed`, so what's the best way of constructing the `sed` arguments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the special meaning of `/` from `sed` then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/^\/\/ //g'  Input_file
```

So I am escaping `/` here by using `\` before it, so it will be taken as a literal character rather than it's special meaning in code. Also if you are happy with above command's result then use `-i` to save the changes in Input_file itself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The slash only has meaning if you allow it.

```
sed 's#^// +##' < file.c
```